# Unable to create mychannel.tx

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am working on Hyperledger Fabric 2.3.

After deploying stack docker-compose file, when I try to create Orderer by Command

**ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-182:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel**

**ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-182:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME**

I get the error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-182:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME

2021-03-12 14:54:53.360 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2021-03-12 14:54:53.362 UTC [viperutil] ReadInConfig -> ERRO 002 Unable to open the config file: 
2021-03-12 14:54:53.367 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> PANI 003 Error reading configuration: open : no such file or directory
2021-03-12 14:54:53.369 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 004 Error reading configuration: open : no such file or directory
panic: Error reading configuration: open : no such file or directory [recovered]
    panic: Error reading configuration: open : no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0000a3d90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:230 +0x545
go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc000010318, 0x4, 0xc000038c00, 0x3d, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0x100
go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(...)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panic(0xc000010320, 0xc000457950, 0x1, 0x1)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:73 +0x99
main.main.func1()
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/configtxgen/main.go:261 +0x176
panic(0xaee240, 0xc00043ec30)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x166
go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0000a3d90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:230 +0x545
go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc0000102b0, 0xcf2604, 0xc13e1c, 0x1f, 0xc000457df8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0x100
go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(...)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(...)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/configtxgen/genesisconfig.Load(0x7ffe28a3772f, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/configtxgen/genesisconfig/config.go:238 +0x1e5
main.main()
    /__w/1/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/configtxgen/main.go:279 +0xfe0
```

[image: Error]
Does anyone know why it is not reading files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the file available to the configtxgen tool. You can do this by setting the  *FABRIC_CFG_PATH* variable.

if you are following the *test-network* example run this command from the *test-network* directory

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/configtx
```

Comment: I have tried that too but the same error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "-configPath ./configtx" so your command will be:

```
../bin/configtxgen -configPath ./configtx -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```

This works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).